# How to add a dot in python numpy ndarray - data type issue

Tags: python, arrays

I have a NumPy `ndarray` that looks like:

```
[[ 0 0 0 1 0]
 [ 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

but I would like to process it to the following form:

```
[[   0.    0.    0.    1.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    1.]]
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: What is your array's datatype?  (`array.dtype`)?

Comment: what you want to do is convert the elements of a numpy array to float data type. that should be a big enough hint!

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you have an array of some integer type.  You probably want to convert to an array of float:

```
array_float = array_int.astype(float)
```

e.g.:

```
>>> ones_i = np.ones(10, dtype=int)
>>> print ones_i
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
>>> ones_f = ones_i.astype(float)
>>> print ones_f
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
```

With that said, I think that it is worth asking *why* you want to process the string representation of your array.  There very well might be a better way to accomplish your goal.